# Random color table cell background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to give every "td" a different background-color.

My javascript:

```
var color = '#';
var letters= ['000000','FF0000','00FF00','0000FF','FFFF00','00FFFF','FF00FF','C0C0C0'];
color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundColor = color;
```

And my HTML:

```
<td id="bg">...</td><td id="bg">...</td>
```

What happens is that every table cell have the same random color, but I need to have them with different color backgrounds.

How can I do it? For loops?

Can you please help me?

Comment: ID's must be unique in a page by defintion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the same id on each td. If these are the only td tags on the page, you can use something like:

```
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td'),
    colors = ['000000','FF0000','00FF00','0000FF','FFFF00','00FFFF','FF00FF','C0C0C0'];

for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].style.backgroundColor = '#' + colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As all said, its not recomended to use same id on multiple tags. But u can define all these to have same class. and use jQuery on the element. Like this

```
<td class="ab">1</td><td class="ab">2</td><td class="ab">3</td>


    var cells = $('td.ab');
    colors = ['000000','FF0000','00FF00','0000FF','FFFF00','00FFFF','FF00FF','C0C0C0'];

    for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        cells[i].style.backgroundColor = '#' + colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So i might be a bit late, but i made this snippet when i had too much time on my hands, what it does: it basically generates a table and sets the background of each cell by generating a hexcode color from a randomly generated string. 
(it also has a hover of a 3x3 grid around the cell your mouse is on).

```
var stringToColour = function(str) {
var hash = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    hash = str.charCodeAt(i) + ((hash << 5) - hash);
}
var colour = '#';
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var value = (hash >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF;
    colour += ('00' + value.toString(16)).substr(-2);
}
return colour;
}
function makeid() {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return text;
}

$('#test td').each(function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', stringToColour(makeid()));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ltt4hL5x/

Comment: Note: as shown in the jsfiddle all is based on the cell index, so there is no need to create countless id's